# Duplicate section error even after using <remove> tag in web.config for IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a site running in a subdirectory of another site. They run in separate app pools. The two sites are running different versions of Entity Framework. So in the web.config in the subdirectory I have:

```
<remove name="entityFramework"/>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

But even with the `<remove>` tag I still get this error:

```
Section or group name 'entityFramework' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.
```

I've also placed `<location>` tags in the parent web.config wherever possible:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

The `<location>` tag is present around the parent web.config's `<entityFramework>` section.

And I've placed `enableConfigurationOverride="false"` in the applicationHost.config files for IIS (both files in System32 and SysWOW64).

How do I prevent the site in the subdirectory from seeing the parent `entityFramework` tag?

EDIT

IIS Version: 7.5.7600.16385

From the parent web.config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

l

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
  </location>
```

From the child web.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <remove name="entityFramework"/>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />    
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
```

l

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
```

EDIT 2

In regards to using `<clear/>`: this causes a series of errors about missing section declarations. If I add back ~100 lines of section declarations I get the error: `An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.` The error persists even if I use `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` in `<system.webServer>`.

Comment: What is the IIS version? Can you show exactly what you have - both the section definition under config sections and the actual EF section.

Comment: @G.Stoynev I've updated the question with your requested info.

Comment: What happens if you remove duplicate section?  Did you try to resolve this issue specifing assembly version?  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="" publicKeyToken="" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="" newVersion="" />
      </dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

Comment: Are you try add  <clear/> to <configSection> and <connectionStrings>?

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm if you tried `clear` instead of `remove` the problem still persist or not?

```
 <configSections>
    <clear/>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />    
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
```

You might read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903345(v=vs.71).aspx)

Hope this will help you

Comment: this error Integrated managed pipeline is related to the IIS, change your IIS setting, usually changing the ApplicationPool settings will solve the issue

Comment: I do have a reproduction and `<clear /> is not helping. There are many references to a Microsoft Connect (now 404) to a post from Microsoft explaining why `'<clear />` and `<remove />` were not intended to be used with `<configSections>`.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you used  but in the parent web.config you posted, the path="." is missing. You're going to need that for it to block the inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, that was a paste error. I've verified that path="." is present and the error remains. I've updated the question to reflect this as well.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this Removeattributes

```
<system.web>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
</system.web>
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/common-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-2010

[Example 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)